# Macro email range + assinatura

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro, microsoft

Bom dia.

Preciso de ajuda em uma macro para envio de e-mails no Outlook 2007.

Possuo uma macro que seleciona um determinado intervalo de células (tudo para a direita e tudo para baixo à partir de uma célula referenciada) e cola em um e-mail, junto com a introdução.
Porém, preciso que minha assinatura seja incluída no fim do e-mail.

Segue o código:

```
`Sub Envia_Email()       
'Seleciona o intervalo de células na planilha ativa.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'desabilite o alerta


Sheets("Base filtrada").Select

Dim email_envio As Variant

email_envio = Range("AP2") 'e-mail para qual será enviado   
descricao = Range("AQ2")

Range("R1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

' Mostrar o envelope na ActiveWorkbook.
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True


With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "Prezado, bom dia!." & vbCr & "Seguem os extratos atualizados nas campanhas:" 'Texto Corpo do e-mail
    .Item.To = email_envio 'Para quem sera enviado
    .Item.Cc = 'Quem será copiado
    .Item.Subject = "Extrato " & descricao 'Assunto do e-mail
    .Item.Send
End With

End Sub`
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#Código

```
Sub Envia_Email()
    'Seleciona o intervalo de células na planilha ativa.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False            'desabilite o alerta


    Sheets("Base filtrada").Select

    Dim email_envio As Variant

    email_envio = Range("AP2")                   'e-mail para qual será enviado
    descricao = Range("AQ2")

    Set rngInicial = Range("R1")
    rngInicial.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496434/7690982
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, HtmlContent As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Set rng = Selection
    'Debug.Print rng.Address 'Verifica os endereços da Seleção
    HtmlContent = "<table>"

    For i = rngInicial.Row To rngInicial.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<tr>"
        For j = rngInicial.Column To rngInicial.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
            HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<td>" & Cells(i, j).Value & "</td>"
        Next
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</tr>"
    Next
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</table>"

    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161351/7690982
    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OMail
        .Display
    End With
    signature = OMail.HTMLbody
    With OMail
        Introducao = "Prezado, bom dia! <br> Seguem os extratos atualizados nas campanhas:" 'Texto Intro Corpo do e-mail
        .To = email_envio
        .Cc = "teste@teste.com.br"               'Quem será copiado
        .Subject = "Extrato " & descricao        'Assunto do e-mail
        '.Attachments.Add
        .HTMLbody = Introducao & "<br>" & HtmlContent & "<br>"& signature
        .Send
    End With
    Set OMail = Nothing
    Set OApp = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True             'habilite o alerta

End Sub
```

> Obs.: Não é recomendado a utilização do `.Select` e `Selection`, há outras maneiras de realizar isso. Ver: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7690982)

#Explicação

###Outlook

Ao invés de:

```
' Mostrar o envelope na ActiveWorkbook.
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
```

Um objeto do Outlook com Late Binding é criado:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161351/7690982
    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OMail
        .Display
    End With
```

###Assinatura

Depois a Assinatura HTML padrão é usada: `signature = OMail.HTMLbody`

###Criar o e-mail e enviar

Depois o e-mail é criado e enviado:

```
With OMail
    Introducao = "Prezado, bom dia!. <br> Seguem os extratos atualizados nas campanhas:" 'Texto Intro Corpo do e-mail
    .To = email_envio
    .Cc = "teste@teste.com.br"               'Quem será copiado
    .Subject = "Extrato " & descricao        'Assunto do e-mail
    '.Attachments.Add 'Para inserir Anexos
    .HTMLbody = Introducao & "<br>" & HtmlContent & "<br>" & signature
    .Send
End With
```

###Criar tabela

A tabela com conteúdo é adicionada com o seguinte código:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496434/7690982
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, HtmlContent As String, i As Long, j As Long
Set rng = Selection
'Debug.Print rng.Address 'Verifica os endereços da Seleção
HtmlContent = "<table>"

For i = rngInicial.Row To rngInicial.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<tr>"
    For j = rngInicial.Column To rngInicial.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<td>" & Cells(i, j).Value & "</td>"
    Next
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</tr>"
Next
HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</table>"
```

Em que as tags de tabulação são adicionadas para cada item do intervalo Excel que contém os dados da tabela.

##EDIT para manter a formatação:

Para manter a formatação, [a função RangetoHTML do Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) pode ser utilizada:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

#Código

Então ao invés de criar a tabela, a função pode ser chamada com:

`HtmlContent = RangetoHTML(Selection)`

E o corpo HTML pode ser construído com:

`.HTMLbody = Introducao & "<br>" & HtmlContent & "<br>" & signature`

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado! Porém, em algumas das células que vão para o e-mail eu tenho algumas formatações condicionais. Tem alguma forma de manter a formatação das células para o e-mail?

Comment: Por exemplo, copiar como se fosse uma imagem e colar, ou apenas manter as formatações mesmo. Pois existe um farol nas células do final.

Comment: Exemplo de farol: <50% = vermelho e >50% = verde. Manter como uma imagem seria copiar exatamente o que está na área selecionada e colar no corpo do e-mail (como um print). Porém, tanto como imagem ou apenas mantendo a formatação já resolveriam o problema.

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Porém, a macro ainda não copia o farol. Segue o link de demonstração do farol na macro antiga (que não inseria a assinatura): https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/vy%2BMDRE2v6swuAOCL3%2BkEQ . Será que é possível copiar tudo para o e-mail?

Comment: Eu fiz com formatação condicional e deu certo. Tem um código para inserir a imagem, mas o problema é que você não consegue inserir como HTML facilmente, precisa primeiro salvar como imagem no computador e depois importar como html. Se inserir como imagem diretamente, a imagem esconde a introdução e a assinatura. Vou editar mais tarde com o código de inserir imagem se você desejar ver como fica...

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Consegui resolver meu problema adaptando algumas linhas do codigo.

Comment: @LeonardoM.Pires Que bom! Que alterações você realizou? Um modo de não inserir as letras é ao invés de utilizar Selection, você pode nomear ranges. Podendo ser ranges definidas manualmente ou por algum algoritmo dinamicamente.

Comment: Daniel, eu precisei inserir algumas novas referencias e ajustes de colunas. Precisei fazer com que a planilha fosse copiada para uma coluna específica, para que mantivesse minhas formatações condicionais, uma vez que elas estão referenciadas por 2 camadas de fórmulas.

Comment: Daniel, Tenho uma planilha com vários gráficos, queria coloca-los no email, mas utilizando essa sua formula, a planilha trava por completo.