# Acrescentar paragrafo em vba

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Eu tenho várias celulas que quero concatenar para enviar um email através do excel

Acontece que a cada celula eu gostaria de ter line breaks mas não estou a conseguir

Já utilizei o WrapText e o Chr() mas não está a resultar, alguém me pode ajudar?

```
 Dim outapp As Outlook.Application
Dim outmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim linha As Integer
Dim folha_origem As String
Dim listamails As String
Dim email As String

'cria e chama os objetos

Set outapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outmail = outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
linha = 7
folha_origem = "Contactos Experts"

'desativar a mensagem de alerta
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

email = ""
While Sheets(folha_origem).Cells(linha, 4).Value <> ""
    listamails = listamails & ";" & Sheets(folha_origem).Cells(linha, 4).Value
    email = email & Chr(10) & Sheets(folha_origem).Cells(linha, 6).Value

    linha = linha + 1
Wend

linha = 7


    With outmail
        'email do destinatário
        .To = listamails
        'titluo da mensagem
        .Subject = email
        'mensagem
        .HTMLBody = Sheets(folha_origem).Range("F7").Value
        'enviar anexos que não existem
        '.Attachments.Add = Range("dshf
        .Display
       ' .Send


    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Mostre o seu código, porque estou conseguindo aqui normalmente.

Comment: @RodrigoRocha já adicionei o código

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o caractere de quebra de linha, que pode usar a função `Chr(10)`.

Para isso, criei um exemplo que funciona, pegando os valores das células.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        MsgBox (Range("A1") & Chr(10) & Range("B1"))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Nova Linha

Para uma nova linha em VBA é possível utilizar as seguintes opções:

```
| Constante |                  Equivalente                   |                                            Descrição                                            |
|-----------|------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| vbCrLf    | Chr (13) + Chr (10)                            | Combinação de alimentação de linha de retorno de carro                                          |
| vbCr      | Chr (13)                                       | Caractere de retorno de carro                                                                   |
| vbLf      | Chr (10)                                       | Caractere de alimentação de linha                                                               |
| vbNewLine | Chr (13) + Chr (10) ou, no Macintosh, Chr (13) | Novo caractere de linha específicos de plataforma; o que for apropriado para a plataforma atual |
```

Segundo a [Documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants)

#### Código

Então o seguinte código pode ser criado para dar compatibilidade entre Sistemas Operacionais Windows e Mac em versões mais antigas do Excel:

```
Function novaLinha() As String
    #If Win32 Or Win64 Then
        novaLinha = Chr(10)
    #ElseIf Mac Then
        novaLinha = vbNewLine
    #End If
End Function

Sub teste()
    MsgBox "oi" & novaLinha & "tchau"
End Sub
```

Ou somente o `vbNewLine` nas mais novas.

#### e-mail em html

Em html o `<br>` é utilizado para nova linha.

[Referência](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

Exemplo:

`"Bom dia,<br>Segue a tabela:"`

ou

```
.HTMLBody = Sheets(folha_origem).Range("F7").Value & "<br>" _
            & Sheets(folha_origem).Range("F8").Value
```

Para mais informações, ver [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/337971/75104)

Comment: o exemplo que me deu funciona, mas no email fico só com a primeira string de toda a concatenação