# Inserir linha em branco em codigo de email vba

Tags: microsoft-excel

Bom dia, estou com um problema ao criar o código vba, consigo inserir uma linha de corpo de e-mail, coloco a segunda linha, mas quando disparo o email, o que deveria ser a segunda linha fica junto com a primeira, segue código abaixo:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set Corpo = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

Corpo = " Olá, segue dados do MTR Nº " & Textnummtr & " - " & Textdata & Chr(10)
Corpo = Corpo & " Item: " & cboitem & Chr(10)





Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "ti@masal.com.br"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "MTR"
.HTMLBody = Corpo
.Send 'or use .Display

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Adiciona a tag `<br>` ? Porque o cliente de email lê HTML

Comment: Veja se [estas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/339107/75104) te ajudam

Comment: Hum, certo, então teria que usar um corpo de email todo em html?
Teria um modelo para me mostrar?

Comment: Substitua `Chr(10)` por `"<br>"`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o comando **vbCrLf**:

```
texto = "linha1" & vbCrLf & "linha2"
msgbox texto
```