# VBA - Como mandar células específicas de uma planilha no corpo de um email

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma aplicação para o meu trabalho em VBA, porém estou tendo dificuldade em mandar somente algumas células no corpo de um email diretamente via outlook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim v1 As String
Dim data As Date
Dim v2 As String
Dim outmail As Object
Dim texto As String
Dim outapp As Object
Dim intervalo As Range



v1 = TextBox1.Value
data = TextBox2.Value
v2 = TextBox3.Value

Sheets("Demandas").Select

Range("A2") = data
Range("B2") = v2
Range("C2") = v1

Sheets("Demandas").Select
Set intervalo = Range("A2:C2").Select


Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outmail = outapp.createitem(0)


With outmail
    .display
    .to = "victoracoelho22@gmail.com"
    .cc = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "Solicitação de nova demanda"
    .body = intervalo

End With


MsgBox ("Sua solicitação foi concluida")

UserForm1.Hide


End Sub
```

Na linha:`Set intervalo = Range("A2:C2").Select` a aplicação sempre dá um erro dizendo que o objeto é obrigatório. Tentei fazer como uma string tambem com a variável texto para anexar as células que eu quero mas deu erro também.

Gostaria de saber se alguem poderia esclarecer isto pra mim, pois estou necessitando muito dessa aplicação.

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Macro email range + assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292574/macro-email-range-assinatura)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá Ecodata espero que te ajude, fiz pequenos ajustes e testei e funcionou!

Segue o trecho de código que você precisa alterar.

```
Sheets("Demandas").Select
Set intervalo = Range("A2:C2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim textoDaSelecao As String

For Each valor In intervalo
    textoDaSelecao = textoDaSelecao & " " & valor
Next

Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outmail = outapp.createitem(0)

With outmail
    .display
    .to = "victoracoelho22@gmail.com"
    .cc = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "Solicitação de nova demanda"
    .body = Mid(textoDaSelecao, 2)
End With
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo!!