# Macro não envia emails

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro, outlook

Minha macro não envia emails... ela tem a seguinte opções, abrir o Outlook e não enviar o e-mail, ou enviar... porem ela só abre e não envia..

```
**' VERIFICAR SE DEVE ENVIAR OU APENAS EXIBIR O EMAIL
        If Worksheets("SUPORTE").[SUPORTE_TIPO_ENVIO] = "Enviar" Then
            .Display
            SendKeys "{SEND}", True ' <<< ALGUMAS VEZES NÃO ENVIAVA IMAGEM USANDO O SEND'
        Else
            .Display
            SendKeys ("^{Enviar}"), True

        End If**
```

Comment: Esse código não envia email ele só simula o pressionar de uma tecla. Para enviar um email em VBA você tem que ativar um objeto da classe `Outlook.Application`.

Comment: Consegui resolver fazendo isso

SendKeys "^{Enter}", True

Ao abrir a janela do outlook ele pressiona o atalho crtl+enter e envia... mas na maquina em questão não funciona

Comment: Ao invés de abrir uma janela e simular um clique ou pressionar de teclas use a [API do Microsoft Otlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/outlook.application). Escrevo isso porque as interfaces com usuário mudam com o tempo, se não for da parte do Aplicativo é da parte do Sistema Operacional a API também evolui porém a cada evolução ela mantém compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Comment: Veja se [este código te ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292640/75104)

Comment: @danieltakeshi você mandou muito bem nesse código +1.

Answer (score 0):

tente dessa forma.

```
 If Worksheets("SUPORTE").[SUPORTE_TIPO_ENVIO] = "Enviar" Then
   .Send
Else
...
```