# Dificuldade para fazer loop em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6

Fiz um código *Visual Basics* para identificar o vencimento de apólices de seguro e subir um *pop-up* e disparar um e-mail alertando caso esteja próximo do vencimento.

A base de dados está constando o Número da Apólice, definida como `valorApolice` na coluna **E**;

o Grupo de objeto segurado, definido como `groupApolice` na coluna **C** ;

e a Data de Vencimento da apólice, definido como `valorData` na coluna **H**.

**Preciso que esse cód replique para todas as linhas preenchidas na base.**

Segue cód que cheguei:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()



Worksheets("plan1").Select
Dim valorData As Date
Dim valorApolice As String
Dim groupApolice As String

valorData = Range("H11").Value
valorApolice = Range("e11").Value
groupApolice = Range("c11").Value


If DateDiff("d", Now(), valorData) < 0 Then
    msgbox "Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencida!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     With OutMail
    .To = "email@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "TESTE: Vencimento de Apólice de Seguro"
    .HTMLBody = "TESTE: Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencida! Entrar em contato com Corretora de Seguros urgente."
    .Send 'Ou .Display para mostrar o email
        End With
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         Set OutMail = Nothing
         Set OutApp = Nothing

ElseIf DateDiff("d", Now(), valorData) < 30 Then
    msgbox "Atenção: a apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", tem vencimento dentro do mês!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly


        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     With OutMail
    .To = "email@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Vencimento de Apólice de Seguro"
    .HTMLBody = "Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencendo! Entrar em contato com Corretora de Seguros."
    .Send 'Ou .Display para mostrar o email
        End With
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         Set OutMail = Nothing
         Set OutApp = Nothing
End If




msgbox "Não há mais outros vencimentos de seguros dentro de um mês.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
Worksheets("MENU").Select
End Sub


msgbox "Não há mais outros vencimentos de seguros dentro de um mês.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
Worksheets("MENU").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Seu e-mail está sem assinatura, para isso verifique [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292640/75104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considere utilizar a estrutura do While.

A estrutura vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
Sub enviar_email()

lin = 1
col = 8 'Coluna H


Do While Sheet1.Cells(lin, col).Value <> ""
    Sheet1.Cells(lin, col).Select
        'Aqui vem o seu código com as regras de negócio
    lin = lin + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: fiz dessa maneira e também deu certo. acabou sendo mais ágil! OBRIGADO!

Answer (score 1):

Se o código está funcionando para uma execução individual, tudo o que você tem que fazer é rodá-lo indefinidamente enquanto alguma condição seja verdadeira. Por exemplo, enquanto a coluna `Base` tiver registros, ele executa para aquela linha. Quando ele chegar em uma linha em que não tiver mais dados ele para.

Assim, é só encapsular o seu código com:

```
Dim x As Integer

Range("E11").Select
NumRows = Range("E11", Range("E11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 1 To NumRows
    valorApolice = ActiveCell.Value
    valorData = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    groupApolice = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)

    ...
    Seu código
    ...

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next x
```

Note que eu tornei suas referências dinâmicas agora. No final, seu código deve ser:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim valorData As Date
Dim valorApolice As String
Dim groupApolice As String
Dim x As Integer


Range("E11").Select
NumRows = Range("E11", Range("E11").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 1 To NumRows
    valorApolice = ActiveCell.Value
    valorData = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    groupApolice = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)

    If DateDiff("d", Now(), valorData) < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencida!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With OutMail
            .To = "email@email.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "TESTE: Vencimento de Apólice de Seguro"
            .HTMLBody = "TESTE: Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencida! Entrar em contato com Corretora de Seguros urgente."
            .Send 'Ou .Display para mostrar o email
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

    ElseIf DateDiff("d", Now(), valorData) < 30 Then
        MsgBox "Atenção: a apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", tem vencimento dentro do mês!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly


        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With OutMail
            .To = "email@email.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Vencimento de Apólice de Seguro"
            .HTMLBody = "Atenção: A apólice de seguro " & valorApolice & " de " & groupApolice & ", está vencendo! Entrar em contato com Corretora de Seguros."
            .Send 'Ou .Display para mostrar o email
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


    Next x

End Sub
```

P.S. Seu código estava com o final duplicado, mas creio que deve você deve ter se enganado na hora de copiar e colar. Já editei a sua pergunta.

Comment: Realmente, copiei e colei duplicado!

Obrigado man!

Só me tira uma dúvida, quando vc definiu X como Interger foi para considerar somente as celulas da colúna que tiver dados?

Comment: X é uma variável temporária usada para controlar quantas vezes vair rodar o loop do `for`.  O número de vezes a rodar o loop está na `NumRows`

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado!