# Como alterar com VBA o e-mail do remetente e inserir a assinatura para disparo de e-mail do outlook?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Tenho enviar um relatório onde preciso inserir uma tabela no corpo do e-mail, porém preciso enviar de um outro e-mail (MBX) do outlook e não do meu pessoal, não estou conseguindo, tentei com o .from mas mesmo assim não funciona.
Além disso preciso inserir a assinatura ao final do e-mail e também não estou conseguindo.
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
Sub Envia_Email_Tabela()


Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Sheets("Tabela").Select

Dim email_envio As Variant

email_envio = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 2) 'e-mail para qual será enviado

Range("A7").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    '.Item.From = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(1, 9) 
    .Introduction = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 4)
    .Item.To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 2)
    .Item.CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 3)
    .Item.Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 5) & "  " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(1, 3) & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("E-MAIL").Cells(3, 6) 'Assunto do e-mail
    .Item.Send


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Enviar do usuário Outlook desejado

Para isso, o [.SendUsingAccount](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) deve ser utilizado e como parâmetro de entrada uma conta do seu Outlook.

Neste exemplo a conta está sendo inserida manualmente ou fixa com `OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2)`, mas um exemplo de loop em `Accounts = OApp.Session.Accounts` está mostrando que há outras maneiras de realizar isso, inclusive criando um Userform para selecionar a conta desejada.

Em algumas versões o `.SendUsingAccount` é um objeto e em outras não, portanto, dependendo da versão fica `Set .SendUsingAccount = OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2)` e em outras `.SendUsingAccount = OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2)`

#### Referência

A referência do Outlook deve ser habilitada em Ferramentas -> Referências...

E habilitar o item "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library"

[image: Ref Outlook]

#### Código

```
Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, Accounts As Object
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim i As Long

Set Accounts = OApp.Session.Accounts

'Verificar as contas do seu Outlook
For Each oAccount In Accounts
    Debug.Print vbCr & "oAccount: " & oAccount
Next
For i = 1 To OApp.Session.Accounts.Count
    Debug.Print OApp.Session.Accounts.item(i)
Next i

Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
With OMail
    .Display
End With

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm
HtmlContent = RangetoHTML(Selection)

With OMail
    'Alterar o número em OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2) para a conta desejada
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2)
    Set .SendUsingAccount = OApp.Session.Accounts.item(2) 'Em algumas versões não é um objeto e o Set deve ser retirado
    Introducao = "Prezado, bom dia!.<br>Seguem os dados:<br>" 'Texto Intro Corpo do e-mail
    Signature = OMail.HTMLbody
    .To = email_envio
    .Cc = "teste@teste.com.br"               'Quem será copiado
    .Subject = "Teste "                      'Assunto do e-mail
    '.Attachments.Add 'Anexos
    .HTMLbody = Introducao & "<br>" & HtmlContent & "<br>" & Signature
    .Send
End With
Set OMail = Nothing
Set OApp = Nothing
```

A função `RangetoHTML()` do [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) deve ser adicionada ao código. Para mais detalhes veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292574/macro-email-range-assinatura/292640#292640)

> Outra forma é o envio por CDO, para mais informações ver [Sending mail from Excel with CDO](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm), que enviará por SMTP e então é possível enviar por qualquer e-mail, não necessitando de um Outlook configurado (caso não seja um usuário do Office Outlook).

Comment: Muito obrigada!! Funcionou perfeitamente com os ajustes